# Dockerfile microdnf -y install fuse-devel throws error

Tags: fuse, ubi

I am using `registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.6-854` image and
`RUN   microdnf -y install fuse-devel` throws error.

```
 ---> Running in bc463d8592cb
error: No package matches 'fuse-devel'
The command '/bin/sh -c microdnf -y install fuse-devel' returned a non-zero code: 1
make: *** [Makefile:196: build-fuse-binary] Error 1
```

Couldnt find a doc on how to install this dependency using microdnf

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.6-854


ADD   register-sys.sh /usr/bin/
RUN   microdnf update --setopt=tsflags=nodocs && \
      microdnf install -y --nodocs hostname subscription-manager
RUN   microdnf update --setopt=tsflags=nodocs && \
      microdnf install -y gcc libstdc++-devel \
      gcc-c++ fuse curl-devel \
      libxml2-devel openssl-devel mailcap \
      git automake make
RUN   microdnf -y install fuse-devel
```

Comment: Is `fuse-devel` available in the standard package repos?

Comment: Not quite sure. How do I verify. Editing question with my complete Dockerfile.

Comment: Why are you compiling s3fs instead of using the packaged version?

Comment: We are providing a plugin for object storage which uses s3fs underlying to mount buckets. But users can have any OS. So we have to compile s3fs for each OS and copy binary depending on user's environment

Comment: was able to do this adding subscription. Issue resolved.

Comment: @ambikanair: We are also facing same issue, Can you please elaborate steps which helped you to solve this issue?